# Send the contents of a datatable to a csv file with headers

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I am trying to send the contents of a datatable to a csv file, with headers. There is a duplicate question but the the accepted answers only seem to work half way. At this point I have mixed and matched the upvoted answers with no luck and need a point in the right direction.

I can write the columns to the file just fine, and I can write data just fine but not together. Also the data never comes out quoted, only comma delimited without quotes.

```
//This is how the FileHelpers class is built
public class ScannedFileInfo
{
    //this prefix will handle the double quotes issue
    //delimiters must reside between double quotes
    //Must specify FieldOrder too
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    [FieldOrder(1)]
    public string DA_Id;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    [FieldOrder(2)]
    public string Name;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    [FieldOrder(3)]
    public string Extension;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    [FieldOrder(4)]
    public string Fullname;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)]
    [FieldOrder(5)]
    public string PathLength;
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
    [FieldOrder(6)]
    public string Directory;
}

//this is how I send it to the file
public static void ImportDirectory(string result, SqlConnection myconn, SqlConnection destConn ,ListBox lbInfo, DataGridView dgView)
{
    //create data table code here - works fine...
    MessageBox.Show("Scan complete. Starting Import...");

    //build file 
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ScannedFileInfo>();
    var orders = new List<ScannedFileInfo>();
    engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader();
    engine.WriteFile(@"C:\DirectoryScan.csv", orders);
    MessageBox.Show("You now have proper labeled columns in your file.");

    //now the data import is successful but it overwrites the column info
    CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv(dt, @"C:\DirectoryScan.csv", ',');
    MessageBox.Show("You now have data in your file, but no columns");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv()` call does not support all of the features of `FileHelpersEngine`. In particular, the field quoting and the column headers are missing. The `CommonEngine` is not as full featured as the `FileHelpersEngine<T>`.

Instead, you should create a list of `ScannedFileInfo` instead of a datatable and then use `FileHelpersEngine<ScannedFileInfo>.WriteFile()`.

```
//create list of ScannedFileInfo here
var records = new List<ScannedFileInfo>();
records.Add(new ScannedFileInfo() { Name = ..., etc... });
// ( or if you prefer, loop through your datatable to build the list)

MessageBox.Show("Scan complete. Starting Import...");

// build file
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ScannedFileInfo>();
engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader();
engine.WriteFile(@"C:\DirectoryScan.csv", records);

MessageBox.Show("You now have data and properly labelled columns in your file.");
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recommend that you look into [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) enough. This nuget package has saved me from pulling my hair out on so many occasions, I can't count them all.

If you're into using it, you can use the configuration settings to quickly set a header record, delimiter, ignore quotes or not, etc.